# How to properly pass two objects through two functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

My series of methods are like so :

```
onUpdateAcrossDown ( findAcrossAndDownWords( across_index, down_index ) )
```

I want to reuse `findAcrossAndDownWords`, so I'd like it to return my two objects that I can pass into other methods if need be.

```
findAcrossAndDownWords: function(across_index, down_index) {
  across_word = across_index[0] // <-- not real, just representing that it becomes an object here.
  down_word = down_index[0]
  return [across_word, down_word] // <-- This is where my problem is. Not sure how to return a double param for my parent function.
}
```

The trouble is, the `return` I am using does not properly pass `across_word, down_word` .

```
onUpdateAcrossDown: function(across_word, down_word) {
 // How do I get across_word and down_word here properly?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the values in an array as parameters to a function, you have to call the function with `.apply()`

```
var results = findAcrossAndDownWords( across_index, down_index );
onUpdateAcrossDown.apply(whatever, results);
```

The `.apply()` method takes two arguments: the value to use for `this` in the called function, and an array containing the parameters to pass.

Comment: strikes again! Thanks so much!

Comment: Is that `whatever` relevant? It's returning `undefined` ;)

Comment: @Trip well I couldn't tell from your code whether the `this` value inside the function is important. If it is, then that's what you pass; otherwise it doesn't really matter.  (By "whatever" I just meant, "something appropriate", in other words.)

Comment: @Trip: I do hope you know what `this` references when you're passing it to `.apply`, because `this` can point to the global object, so you might be creating unwanted globals or trying to access undefined properties

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem well if he's passing `undefined` then it's probably OK, so long as it's working.

Comment: @Pointy, sure, but in his last comment I thought he said he was passing `this`: _Boom! I pass this and everything is awesome!_ Just wanted to hint at possible dangers if he is passing `this`

Comment: Nope, I need that global to go through. Thanks Elias.

Answer (score 1):

You could, instead of nesting calls, pass the second function as an argument:

```
findAcrossAndDownWords(across_index, down_index, onUpdateAcrossDown);

function findAcrossAndDownWords(object1, object2, callNext)
{
    //do stuff
    return callNext(object1, object2);
}
```

Or, change the function definition of the second function to:

```
function UpdateAcrossDown(anArray)
{
    var obj1 = anArray[0], obj2 = anArray[1];
}
```

*Or*, if you're allways going to call the same function:

```
function findAcrossAndDownWords(object1, object2, callNext)
{
    //do stuff
    return UpdateAcrossDown(object1, object2);//loses call context
    return UpdateAcrossDown.apply(this,arguments);//preserve called context
    //or even
    return UpdateAcrossDown.apply(this,[object1,object2]);//preserve called context
}
```